# How to parallelize this code

Tags: parallelization

Here I obtained one code which should tests some zeros of the poly for various g, but sometimes I have to many cycles because of step and I need to parallelize the running on all cores. Classical ParallelDo instead the Do doesn't work. What to do further

```
 poly=g*x^3+21*x^2-1.23*x+7.3247*g*I*x^2;


 LM = {};
 Do[
 Lroots = x /. NSolve[(poly /. {g -> G}) == 0, x];

 res = 0;
 Do[
 root = Lroots[[i]];
 If[Im[root] >= 0,
 L1 = Drop[Lroots, {i}];
 res = res + 1/(Times @@ (root - L1));
 ];
  , {i, 1, Length[Lroots]}
   ];
  M = 1/((4*G^2)*res);
  AppendTo[LM, M];

 , {G, 0.001, 15, 0.01}
 ];
```

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a bit further on what you try to calculate with the code? Maybe the `Do` can be avoided or is the parallelization of the `Do` the main point of the question? Do you perhaps intend to calculate an Integral along the real axis using Jordan's Lemma? (`Im[root]>=0` and summing `res` as in residues makes me think that way)

Comment: Just to use all cores in computing the M